# Creating a Magento Conditional Based on Region (State) in an Email Template

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to create an (Order/Invoice) Email Template with a condition in it such as this?

```
{{if order.getBillingAddress().getRegion() == "Arizona"}}
    <h1>Hi Arizona!</h1>
{{/if}}

{{if order.getBillingAddress().getRegion() == "North Carolina"}}
    <h1>Hi North Carolina!</h1>
{{/if}}
```

I have tried this, and it's as if the 'if' statements are being ignored when I sent a test email. **I would like to keep this within the UI for Email Templates** and not have to alter a PHP template everytime a new condition becomes necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What does `order.getBillingAddress().getRegion()` return?

Comment: I believe the 'if' statements are being ignored. I receive both Hi Arizona! and Hi North Carolina! when I do a test email.

Comment: @Pekka -- `order.getBillingAddress().getRegion()` returns the Region or State used in the customer's order. Apparently it does not return it in a format that means anything to PHP.